# Are the white things on a bread normal?

Tags: food-safety, bread, mold

I have a piece of olive bread which was good by April 16. I have seen some white things on them since I got them on April 17, and have kept it in refrigerator. Are they normal and safe to eat?

Will it make it safer to eat by boiling the bread?

Thanks.

without plastic package:

[image]
[image]

within plastic package:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a clearer picture, maybe without the plastic? I think I see spots of mold but it's kind of hard to tell. Or are you're saying it wasn't there when you bought it and now it is? That'd be mold.

Comment: Also boiling bread is just going to make... disintegrated mush. Safe or not, it won't really be bread anymore.

Comment: Updated with photos without plastic package. I saw the white things when I got them one day after its last good day.

Answer (score 6):

From what I can tell from the picture, most of the white stuff is flour; it was likely like that when you bought it, but only you & your memory know for sure. The non-bread & non-white occasional spots in the picture appear to be the olives.

Overall, unless you spot obvious mold, which is more often green than white, I think you are OK to consume it. But it's nearly a week past its date, so I'd consume it soon.

Comment: I think I agree. The white stuff looks like flour here, though there are a few darker spots that are hard to tell about - could be grayish mold, could be shadows.

Comment: This sort of bread often has flour on it, and mould only a day after the best before date is unlikely unless it's been kept somewhere very warm and humid.